# MS Access Form Filtering syntax

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, syntax, filtering

I have been churning on this for way too long and can really use some help with a Form filter in Access.  I am building a database to track guitar builds, clients, orders, billing, etc...

I have a Subform [frm_SelectParts] that lists parts available for any given build.  This form displays the various parts that I may want to add to an order.  For example, select this body, this neck, these tuners, these pickups...

The form's record source is a query [qry_SelectParts].  The query basically returns all parts from the Parts Master [tbl_PartMaster] table, with a few fields from other tables, displaying all parts for Guitar, Bass, and both (in the case of switches and knobs that are not instrument specific).

I have a Part Category Dropdown [cmbo_PartCategory] on my [frm_SelectParts] subform that displays Part Categories (Bodies, Necks, Tuners, Pickups… etc).   I also have a textbox that pulls the Instrument type [txt_InstType] (1 = Guitar or 2 = Bass) from a main form [frm_OrderMain].

My hope is to apply the filter on the AfterUpdate event of the [cmbo_PartCategory] dropdown.  I want to filter the returned data based on Part Category selected in the dropdown and the [txt_InstType] textbox, showing (Guitar or Bass).  This way if I select Bodies from the dropdown, I only see Guitar bodies (if I'm building a guitar) or Bass Bodies (if a bass)

Here is the SQL for the [qry_SelectParts] query that the [frm_SelectParts]form is using:

```
SELECT tbl_PartMaster.PartDescritoion, tbl_Supplier.Supplier, 
tbl_PartMaster.PartCost, tbl_TEMP_OrderDtl.OrderQty, tbl_PartMaster.InstSpec_ID, 
tbl_PartMaster.PartCategory_ID
FROM tbl_Supplier 
LEFT JOIN (tbl_PartMaster LEFT JOIN (tbl_OrderMain 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_TEMP_OrderDtl ON tbl_OrderMain.Order_ID = tbl_TEMP_OrderDtl.Order_ID) 
ON tbl_PartMaster.Part_ID = tbl_TEMP_OrderDtl.Part_ID) 
ON tbl_Supplier.Supplier_ID = tbl_PartMaster.Supplier_ID;
```

I’m struggling with the filter syntax in the Code Builder off of the AfterUpdate event on the [cmbo_PartCategory] dropdown.

I’m trying to filter the queried data to display only tbl_PartMaster.PartCategory_ID = [combo_PartCategory] and tbl_PartCategory.InstSpec_ID = [txt_InstType] or 3

*InstType_ID is Instrument Type ID.  1= Guitar, 2 = Bass, 3 = Guitar/Bass to differentiate parts for specific instruments.  Again, some parts will work on both.  So if I’m looking for Bass parts, I will want InstSpec_ID = 2 or 3.  For guitar parts, InstSpec_ID = 1 or 3.

I've tried using WHERE clauses in the query itself and kept getting parameter message boxes when opening the form.  I also tried coding the filter myself based on what I've found online for guidance and had no success. This is why I hope to have the dropdown initiate the form filter.

I hope I've explained this clearly.  Any help with how to code this in the Code Builder would be greatly appreciated, or any better solutions welcome.  I'm not a strong Access user.   I have probably spent a week trying different things to get this to work and finally had enough.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What purpose is served by having form bound to this complex query? It makes no sense for a data entry concept. If you want to select parts for a build order, then you should probably be using a combobox with tbl_PartMaster as its source and creating records in a table OrderDetails and form bound to that table. That would be conventional approach. Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Might want to correct spelling of field `PartDescritoion`.

Comment: I understand.  I will give this a try.  Thank you, June7.  I know I have lots to learn, and I appreciate your feedback (and proofreading!).  Will let you know how I make out.